# Need to show days, hours, minutes and seconds between two dates in PHP

Tags: php, countdown

I need to display the difference in days, hours, minutes and seconds between two dates, in PHP.  I've already tried the suggestions offered here:

[Create Day, Hour, Minute and Second countdown in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148008/create-day-hour-minute-and-second-countdown-in-php)

And they all give incorrect results.  Here is an example:

```
$startdate = "2014-03-20 12:34:56";
$enddate =   "2014-04-01 13:34:56";

$diff = strtotime($enddate) - strtotime($startdate);

$temp = $diff/86400; // (60 sec/min * 60 min/hr * 24 hr/day = 86400 sec/day)
$dd = floor($temp); $temp = 24*($temp-$dd); //Days
$hh = floor($temp); $temp = 60*($temp-$hh); //Hours
$mm = floor($temp); $temp = 60*($temp-$mm); //Minutes
$ss = floor($temp); //Seconds

echo $dd." days\n".
     $hh." hours\n".
     $mm." minutes\n".
     $ss." seconds";
```

The results with the two timestamps I've specified *should* be:

```
11 days
1 hour
0 minutes
0 seconds
```

But when I run this, it's giving me:

```
12 days
0 hours
0 minutes
0 seconds
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use DateTime class of PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Daylight savings time perhaps?

Comment: March has 31 days, so maybe what you expected was 12 days, 1 hour 0 minutes 0 seconds, not 11 days etc.

Comment: `date_create($startdate)->diff(date_create($enddate))->format('%a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds')` would be a more modern way to do this, and would give the correct result, rather than doing the arithmetic yourself.

Comment: @salathe, the _correct result_, in this case, depends on who or what uses it (see my answer).

Comment: What is missing from my answer for you to accept it?

Answer (score 3):

The output you get is correct. The [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) in your timezone changes near the end of March. If you consider the output NOT to be correct (you are free to do so), you can do this:

```
$diff = strtotime($enddate." UTC") - strtotime($startdate." UTC");
```

and then the rest of your calculation (but: see the EDIT below).

[`UTC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the "Coordinated Universal Time", so that the above is a "daylight-savings-less" difference.

If you don't explicitly supply a timezone (like `UTC`) to `strtotime()`, it will use the default timezone, i.e., the output of `date_default_timezone_get()`.

**EDIT**

It turns out that your algorithm on my machine, with the above modification and with your datetimes, prints the following:

```
12 days
0 hours
59 minutes
59 seconds
```

how comes? The reason is that you should never rely on the exactness of floating point arithmetics, in particular of division, except in rare cases. The result of your division is `12.041666666667`, which, a couple of lines later, causes your hours to be `0.99999999999999` instead of `1.0`.

Instead of fixing the algorithm, I suggest to follow the advice by @salathe, and to do this in order to get the result you expect (which may not be the result someone/something else expects):

```
$diff = date_create($startdate)->diff(date_create($enddate));
echo $diff->format("%a days\n%h hours\n%i minutes\n%s seconds\n");
```

Otherwise, a fix of your algorithm, that works for both interpretations of the difference, is:

```
if ($ignore_dst) {
   $diff = strtotime($enddate." UTC") - strtotime($startdate." UTC");
} else {
   $diff = strtotime($enddate)        - strtotime($startdate);
}
$ddss =  $diff          % 86400;
$dd   = ($diff - $ddss) / 86400;
$hhss =  $ddss          %  3600;
$hh   = ($ddss - $hhss) /  3600;
$mmss =  $hhss          %    60;
$mm   = ($hhss - $mmss) /    60;
$ss   =  $mmss          %    60;
```

Here all variables are integers (you can check with `var_dump()`), but even if they were not, division is only done when you already have a multiple of the divisor, which guarantees the result.

Answer (score 2):

Daylight saving changed between

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use the **date()** function?

```
 date("d", $timestamp); // day
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The Questioneer will print out the day/month/year/or other. Why he dont use the right PHP function?

Comment: The OP wants to output a difference between datetimes - how should he use `date()` for that?

Comment: Uh yea, but read: Why he dont use **the right** PHP function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand - ich gebe es auf

Answer (score 0):

```
            $days = 0;
            $hours = 0;
            $minutes = 0;
            $seconds = 0;
            $limit_date = new DateTime("2022-06-23 01:11:59");
            $time_now = new DateTime("2022-06-22 01:10:00");
            $diffInSeconds = $limit_date->getTimestamp() - $time_now->getTimestamp(); 
            if ($diffInSeconds > 0){
              if ($diffInSeconds > 60) {
                  $d = (float)((($diffInSeconds/60)/60)/ 24);
                  $d_point = $d - floor($d);
                  $h = (float)($diffInSeconds/60)/60;
                  $h = (float)($d_point * 24);
                  $h_point = $h - floor($h);
                  $m = (float)(($h-floor($h)) * 60);
                  $m = $h_point * 60;
                  $m_point = $m - floor($m);
                  $s = (float)($m_point * 60);
                  $days = intval($d);
                  $hours = intval($h);
                  $hours = intval($h);
                  $minutes = intval($m);
                  $seconds = intval($s);
              } else {
                  $seconds = $diffInSeconds;
              }
            }
           echo  $days . " " . $hours. ":" . $minutes. ":" . $seconds;
```

[image]